# How does `Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i)` work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I may be missing something obvious here but could someone breakdown step by step why `Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

I didn't understand in detail why this works

Comment: *Array.from() lets you create Arrays from:  array-like objects (objects with a length property and indexed elements)* and *mapFn Optional. Map function to call on every element of the array.*

Comment: I guess you should read this to understand that `(v,k)=>k` is same as `function(v,k){return k;}` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions and this to understand object creation with 5 undefined elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When Javascript checks if a method can be called, it uses [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_JavaScript). That means when you want to call a method `foo` from some object, which is supposed to be of type `bar`, then it doesn't check if this object is really `bar` but it checks if it has method `foo`.

So in JS, it's possible to do the following:

```
let fakeArray = {length:5};
fakeArray.length //5
let realArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
realArray.length //5
```

First one is like *fake* javascript array (which has property `length`). When  `Array.from` gets a value of property `length` (5 in this case), then it creates a real array with length 5.

This kind of *fakeArray* object is often called *arrayLike*.

The second part is just an arrow function which populates an array with values of indices (second argument).

This technique is very useful for mocking some object for test. For example:

```
let ourFileReader = {}
ourFileReader.result = "someResult"
//ourFileReader will mock real FileReader
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for - I wasn't aware of duck typing before. Admittedly my question wasn't well phrased.

Answer (score 19):

```js
var arr1 = Array.from({
    length: 5 // Create 5 indexes with undefined values
  },
  function(v, k) { // Run a map function on said indexes using v(alue)[undefined] and k(ey)[0 to 4]
    return k; // Return k(ey) as value for this index
  }
);
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Seems like `Array.from` also calls an implicit `Array.prototype.fill()` or does some other magic. Because if we create a sparse array like `var arr = []; arr.length=5;` we couldn't map over that array, even if we (theoretical) have 5 undefined values.

Comment: v can be replaced by underscore `_` because we are making a new array from k

Answer (score 8):

On developer.mozilla.org page about array.from, nobody tell us that `mapFn` can take 2 arguments, for example `v` and `k`: `v` is value of current element, `k` is index of element. So here's the deal.

`{length:5}` create an object without any value, but with `length` equal to `5`;

`(v, k) => k` is an arrow function that assign index number of current element to that element value.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument in the arrow function is always the index with Array.from() method

```js
x=Array.from({length:5},(v,i,k)=>k)
console.log(x)
//Expected output Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

x=Array.from({length:5},(v,i,k)=>v)
console.log(x)
//Expected output Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

x=Array.from({length:5},(v,i,k)=>i)
console.log(x)
//Expected output Array(5) [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

x=Array.from({length:5},()=>[])
console.log(x)
//Expected Output Array(5) [ [], [], [], [], [] ]

x=Array.from({length:5},()=>{})
console.log(x)
//Expected Output Array(5) [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```