# Uint8Array.from behaviour is not the same as new Uint8Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a `Uint8Array` from an `ArrayBuffer` in javascript. However, if I use the normal `Uint8Array.from` class method, I end up with an empty array, whereas if I pass the buffer through the constructor I get the correct `Uint8Array`.

I had assumed that these operations would be equivalent, but they are clearly not. Could someone please help me understand why this doesn't work? (if it helps, I am just typing this test case in the console of Chrome 87).

```
> test_data = Uint8Array.from([1,2,3,4])
 Uint8Array(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]

> view = new DataView(test_data.buffer)
DataView(4) {}

> Uint8Array.from(view.buffer) // this doesn't work for some reason ?
Uint8Array []

> new Uint8Array(view.buffer)
Uint8Array(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ArrayBuffers aren't iterable.

Comment: in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from it says: `The TypedArray.from() method creates a new typed array from an array-like or iterable object`. So is an ArrayBuffer not considered array-like?

Comment: No an ArrayBuffer is nor iterable nor ArrayLike, you need a BufferView to be able to access its underlying data, the ArrayBuffer in itself is opaque and doesn't have indexed properties.

Comment: See: [How does \`Array.from({length: 5}, (v, i) => i)\` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40528798), I'm guessing the behaviour for `Uint8Array.from` is more or less the same as `Array.from`, it checks the object for a `.length` property (or if it is iterable), since `view.buffer` isn't any of these it won't be able to build a `Uint8Array` for you